# How to hide the titlebar in freeform multiwindow mode?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, multi-window

In an activity I can hide the titlebar using the following code, but when the Activity is started freeform multiwindow mode the title bar appears with x and multiwindow icon. How to hide the titlebar in freeform multiwindow mode ?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            final WindowInsetsController insetsController = getWindow().getInsetsController();
            if (insetsController != null) {
                insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
            }
        } else {
            getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            );
        }
```

Comment: I suspect that is not possible, so the user can move and close the window.

Comment: I spent half the day trying to find a way, thanks for letting me know !